# jBoss is hanging at "Loading profile..." output line

Tags: jboss5.x

I am trying to start a jBoss 5.1.0.GA instance and the output console is hanging on the `[ProfileServiceBootstrap] Loading profile: ProfileKey@3f5f852e[domain=default, server=default, name=default]` line.

The jBoss instance is copied from a remote server on which it works well.
There is not so much work logged (no more than 50 rows) and No error is displayed in console while starting up.
I understand that there may be some dependencies/connections/etc that it needs and are not satisfied, but I would expect an error to be thrown. Instead, it only hangs, without any other issue being reported.

I hope that this message will sound familiar to others that have worked more with older versions of jBoss and may direct me to investigate potential root causes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not proud of my findings... :) the issue was in fact that the logs were set not to write into the console. So, after looking for other log files, I found that the server started with the very well known statement `Started in 1m:21s:836ms`...

It is not really an issue nor an answer, but I leave this here in case others will find themselves in the same "I do not see the logs" situation (which should be also the title).
Note: in order logs to be shown, I have modified /server/default/conf/jboss-log4j.xml